Drupal multisite with path-based, nested, subdirectories not loading beyond homepage
I am hosting several Drupal sites on an internal server, and I'm attempting to set up a Drupal multisite environment using path-based subdirectories instead of subdomains.
Current setup

All of my sites leverage the same sub/domain, e.g. subdomain.example.com.
Each site is located in /sites on the server, e.g. the "Travel" website directory is served from /sites/travel, the "Blog" website directory is served from /sites/blog.
I use an Apache alias to map the path /travel to /sites/travel/web
(since the docroot for Drupal 8+ is web).
This setup works well for individual sites like subdomain.example.com/travel and subdomain.example.com/blog.

My goal
Now, I'm setting up a new multisite under the path /hub and would like to configure subsites in directories under it:

The main site should be accessible at subdomain.example.com/hub.
The first subsite should be accessible at subdomain.example.com/hub/site1.
The second subsite should be accessible at subdomain.example.com/hub/site2.

The sites.php file is set up to accommodate:

subdomain.example.com.hub
subdomain.example.com.hub.site1
subdomain.example.com.hub.site2

Issue
With a RewriteBase /hub along with 2 symlinks for each subsite, I can access the /hub site correctly, and I can load the homepage for the subsites (/hub/site1 and /hub/site2), but any paths beyond the homepage on the subsites return a 404 error (from /hub).
Question
What is the correct way to configure Apache, symlinks, and/or .htaccess to support this setup and allow the subsites' paths to resolve correctly?
Here’s what I’ve tried so far

Apache alias: I've created aliases for /hub, /hub/site1, and /hub/site2.
Symlinks: I’ve created symlinks in the /web directory for /web/site1 -> /web
.htaccess: I've attempted many variations of rewrite conditions here, but to no avail.

How can I make sure that subsite paths like /hub/site1/somepage are properly handled and do not return 404 errors from /hub?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
